# my if this AND this then that statement doesnt work

Tags: jquery, if-statement, scroll, width

i want it to log something if both requirement are met, but i cant get it to work

```
//change css on scroll
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var Wwidth = $(window).width();

    if ((scroll <= 550) && (Wwidth <= 550)) {
        console.log('small');
    } else {

        console.log('big');
    }
});
```

the console.log is just for this question purpose.
like this it works, but i want it to see if both requirements are met

```
//change css on scroll
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var Wwidth = $(window).width();

    if (scroll <= 550) {
        console.log('small');
    } else {

        console.log('big');
    }
});
```

Comment: Are 'small' and 'big' variables you've defined somewhere or are you just wanting to output text to the console?  If the latter, wrap them in quotes: `console.log('small')` etc.

Comment: When I try the code it works just as expected. What do you mean exactly when you say that you can't get it to work? What happens when you run the code? Do you get any error message.

Comment: It works http://jsfiddle.net/cos23t3p/

Answer (score 0):

For those lines:

```
console.log(small);
console.log(big);
```

are the 'small' and 'big' defined somewhere as variables?

Or do you simply wanna do

```
console.log('small'); 
console.log('big');
```

Comment: i have other things inside it, the console.log is just for question purpose
but the '' where good,
like this it works, but i want it to see if both requirements are met
  
  //change css on scroll
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var Wwidth = $(window).width();

        if (scroll <= 550) {
            console.log('small');
        } else {

            console.log('big');
        }
    });

Comment: Then, what do you get in the console output window? For debugging purpose, why not do console.log('Scroll Value: '+scroll); console.log('Wwidth Value: '+Wwidth); to see what are the actual value of those variables.